# Multiple Problems with Firestore Database Web Console

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I worked with my collection, in first level(root tree) firestore DB. I tried to remove it, but this is impossible, I see the endless progress(>1Hr) in my Google firebase firestore web console.
After that, I programmatically deleted all the collection documents from my Android application.
Android application does not load data from this collection, the list is empty, but in the console, the collection still exists with many old items.

After that I create one more collection and insert documents programmatically from Android. All is well, I get data from the collection, I save, but in the console collection does not exist.

New first level collections are also not created from the web console.

What am I doing wrong? Mysticism or I broke Google?